# How would unencapsulate an Unsorted Array structure’s Fetch algorithm?

Tags: data-structures, encapsulation, deep-copy

```html
//access the node (assumes the node is in the structure)
i=0;
while(targetKey!=data[i].key()){
i++
}

// return a a copy of the node to the client 
return data[i].deepCopy();
```

Here is a sample of my code to help better understand the question. Any suggestions would be nice. When it says unencapsulate the structure, does it mean that I will reveal the implementation details of the deepCopy() method. Referring to specifically line 7 as the question in hand which is **return data[i].deepCopy();.** Here is partial code above: